# How can python bypass my prior code to run later codes first?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

```
import asyncio
import time


async def func():
    print('task start')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('task end')


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func())
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(func())
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(func())
    s = time.monotonic()
    print('main start', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task1
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task2
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task3
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task4
    print('main end', time.monotonic() - s)


asyncio.run(main())
```

This code gives results as below:

```
main start 0.0
task start
task start
task start
task start
task end
task end
task end
task end
main continue 10.0
main continue 10.0
main continue 10.0
main end
```

But how is this possible ,python bypassed my prior print calls ,
run the awaitables first and then go back to make print calls ,
how shall I make sense of this ?

Comment: try to flush stdout.  `print(..., flush=True)`

Comment: Worth noting that your code doesn't always output in the order you've shown, after testing a few times I have seen sometimes the `continue` and `end` are mixed, as you have essentially created a race condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your tasks are sleeping 10 seconds, then continue and finish almost instantly.
So all the `await` calls will unlock at the same time since when task 1 if finished, all tasks will be finished as well.

You are right in the sense that you technically could have intertwined prints between `task end` and `main continue` but I guess this is an implementation detail that everything appears grouped.

I think you can have a better understanding of what is going on using this tweaked script:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def func(task_nb, wait):
    print('[%s] task start' % task_nb)
    await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    print('[%s] task end' % task_nb)


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func(1, 1))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func(2, 5))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(func(3, 7))
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(func(4, 2))
    s = time.monotonic()
    print('main start', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task1
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task2
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task3
    print('main continue', time.monotonic() - s)
    await task4
    print('main end', time.monotonic() - s)


asyncio.run(main())
```

You will have a more interesting `await` behaviour:

```py
main start 1.81000359589234e-07
[1] task start
[2] task start
[3] task start
[4] task start
[1] task end
main continue 1.0019499360005284
[4] task end
[2] task end
main continue 5.001785704000213
[3] task end
main continue 7.003587035000237
main end 7.003632674000073
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does what it is supposed to do according to the specification of `asyncio`, but perhaps you are misunderstanding what a "task" is.

From the docs:

> `asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None)`
>
> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object.

This means that as you've created 4 tasks at the beginning of your main, they are all scheduled to execute starting at the same time.  And so they all print `task start` together, then print `task end` together, at which point, all of your `await`s instantly fall through as all tasks have completed at the same time (10 seconds later). So finally you see `main continue 10.0` 3 times.

Try this code, I believe it will have the behavior you are expecting.

```py
async def main():
    task1 = func()
    task2 = func()
    task3 = func()
    task4 = func()
    ...
```